# Best estimate of the Mertens function without assuming the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I'm searching the best known upper bound for the Mertens function, but without assuming the Riemann hypothesis.

Landau, in 1901, have proved that $M(x)= O(x \exp(-c\sqrt{\ln x})$, but I am unable to find the current estimate in the classical literature.

Comment: The best known zero-free region, due to Korobov and Vinogradov (see [the introduction here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/zeros.pdf)), gives the same upper bound for $M(x)$ as the best known error term in the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Greg Martin said in a comment, the Korobov-Vinogradov zero-free region for $\zeta(s)$ yields
$$M(x)\ll x\exp\bigl(-c(\log x)^{3/5}(\log\log x)^{-1/5}\bigr).$$
For a reference, see Satz 3 in Section V.5 of Walfisz: Weylsche Exponentialsummen in der neueren Zahlentheorie (VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften, Berlin, 1963).

This bound cannot be improved (essentially) without improving the Korobov-Vinogradov zero-free region, see Allison: On obtaining zero-free regions for the zeta-function from estimates of $M(x)$, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. **67** (1970), 333-337.

Comment: Many thanks.I knew that the zero-free region of Vinogradov-Korobov had an influence on M (x) but the reference ...