# Partial sums of the Möbius function on arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

There is a result of Soundararajan on the upper bound of the partial sums of the Möbius function assuming GRH [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0723). [Suger and Halupczok](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/functiones-et-approximatio-commentarii-mathematici/volume-48/issue-1/Partial-sums-of-the-M%C3%B6bius-function-in-arithmetic-progressions-assuming/10.7169/facm/2013.48.1.6.full) find an analogous bound for $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\n \equiv a \bmod q}}\mu(n)$, also assuming GRH. However, without assuming GRH, what are some non-trivial upper bounds on $$\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\n \equiv a \bmod q}}\mu(n)?$$ It does not have to be the most optimal one (although I would appreciate being linked to such a bound). In fact, I don't even know of a non-trivial bound not assuming GRH on $\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$. Thanks!

Comment: For the sum over all $n\leq x$ see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/293738/30186)

Comment: This question is also discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381550/best-known-bounds-for-left-sum-nx-munk-right-reference-request

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A variant of the Siegel-Walfisz theorem states that there is a constant $c>0$ with the following property. For any $A>0$ and $q\leq(\log x)^A$, we have
$$\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\n \equiv a \bmod q}}\mu(n)\ll_A x\exp\left(-c\sqrt{\log x}\right).$$
See Exercise 13 for Section 11.3 of Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Are there also some results when $q\ge (\log x)^A$? Actually, I am quite satisfied as long as I can be sure that $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\n \equiv a \bmod q}}\mu(n)=o(x)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @RemarkablyUnremarkable: One can go up to $q\leq\exp(2c\sqrt{\log x})$, with the same $c>0$ as before, but there will be a main term depending on a possible Siegel zero for quadratic Dirichlet characters modulo $q$. If the Siegel zero does not exist, then the same bound holds true as for $q\leq(\log x)^A$. See Exercises 12-13 for Section 11.3.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.