# What are some estimates for $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n, m \leq N\\ n, m \equiv a \bmod q\\n \not= m}}\mu(n)\mu(m)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Consider the sum $$\sum_{\substack{n,m\leq N\\ n, m \equiv a \bmod q\\n \not= m}}\mu(n)\mu(m).$$ What are some of the best known estimates regarding this sum? For the case where we allow $n=m$,  I am aware of the [following preprint of Nunes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0684.pdf). But what the sum above? Here, $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Comment: Isn't this sum $( \sum_{ { n \leq N , n \equiv a\operatorname{ mod }q }} \mu(n) )^2 -  \sum_{ { n \leq N ,n \equiv a \operatorname{ mod }q }} \mu(n)^2$? I would estimate the two terms separately.

Comment: I just realised that this is not a clever question. For $q\leq (\log N)^A$, GH from MO points out that the first sum in your comment is estimated by Siegel-Walfisz (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390774/partial-sums-of-the-m%c3%b6bius-function-on-arithmetic-progressions). So, I am guessing that without conditions on $q$, there aren't many good estimates of the sum in the question available?

Comment: Not that I am aware of (except under GRH and in the function field model).

Comment: No problem, thanks.